# Migration from Vue2 to Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3

I am trying to migrate Vue2 to Vue3. For this I uppdated most of the packages to their latest. I deleted some of my packages to make it more summarized but here is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
        "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.17.1",
        "axios": "^1.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "cypress": "^9.6.1",
        "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
        "eslint": "^8.24.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.9.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "postcss": "^8.4.17",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.55.0",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "vue": "^3.2.40",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
        "vue-template-babel-compiler": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
        "worker-loader": "^3.0.8",
        "zen-observable": "^0.8.15"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@formkit/auto-animate": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
        "@sentry/browser": "^6.11.0",
        "@sentry/integrations": "^6.11.0",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^6.11.0",
        "@stoplight/spectral-cli": "^6.2.1",
        "@vue/compat": "^3.2.40",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.40",
        "el-table-infinite-scroll": "^3.0.1",
        "element-plus": "^2.2.17",
        "element-ui-el-table-draggable": "^1.2.10",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "fsevents": "^1.2.9"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "^12.0.0"
    }
}
```

And here is my webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin');

let plugins = [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  }),
  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /en/),
];

  plugins.push(
    new SentryWebpackPlugin({
      authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
      org: '',
      project: 'front-end',

      include: './public',
      ignore: ['node_modules', 'webpack.mix.js'],
    }),
  );
mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .override((webpackConfig) => {
    webpackConfig.module.rules = webpackConfig.module.rules.map(function (rule) {
      if (rule.test == '/\\.vue$/') {
        rule.use[0].loader = 'vue-loader';
      }
      return rule;
    });
  })
  .vue({ version: 3 })
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/element.scss', 'public/css')
  .version()
  .options({
    uglify: {
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true,
        },
      },
    },
    terser: {
      parallel: false,
    },
  })
  .webpackConfig({
    plugins,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': __dirname + '/resources/assets/js/components',
        '&': __dirname + '/resources/assets/sass',
      },
    },
    devServer: {
      allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
  })
```

But I am getting an error like this:

```
app.js:43225 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
    at eval (app.js?e348:51:5)
    at ./resources/assets/js/app.js (app.js:6135:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:43222:33)
    at app.js:44563:115
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:43269:23)
    at app.js:44569:53
    at app.js:44571:12
```

I am really confused about this error and I have no clue how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check yourself the code at the specified location. It's very likely it refers to Vue.use, which doesn't exist in Vue 3. This means that you didn't update some of plugins. You can use vue compat package but it doesn't guaranteed that V2 libs will be workable, so proceed from that you need to upgrade every lib

Comment: I think it is related to laravel-mix but couldnt figure out how

Comment: I don't see a connection. The code from webpack.mix.js is Node code, it isn't evaluated in a browser and shouldn't be included into app.js. It's a coincidence that `use` property is used there either. `Any way, only you check what exactly the error refers to.

Comment: I updated all of my packages but getting the same error. Before I update my applicaiton in app.js 'window.Vue = Vue;' this exists but I dont know how to change it with app. Do you want me to share app.js also?

Comment: Yes, this may help, although it wouldn't be the first thing to check. It's more important why window.Vue is needed

Answer (score 0):

Vue2 and Vue3 are initiated (or mounted) differently.
From the [Getting started Page in Vue2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started):

```
import Vue from "vue"

Vue.use(<yourPlugin>)

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
})
```

[In Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#what-is-vue)

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app =  createApp({
  ...
})
app.use(<yourPlugin>)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: I added that but still getting the same error. Should I add 'rule.use[0].options.compiler = require('@vue/compiler-sfc');' to my webpack.mix.js?